# IFormFile Upload Image ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Sorry to bother you guys but i have a problem that i have no idea how to solve and i have been browsing for days now and trying different solution.

So i am building a website where i want to implement a user section when the User can Upload his personal image as picture Profile.

And here is where the problem i raise, when i run the code, it return always as null.

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeCreateViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if(model.Photo != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "EmpImg");
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.Photo.FileName;
                using(var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await model.Photo.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }


            }
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Surname = model.Surname,
                Email = model.Email,
                Area = model.Area,
                PhotoPath = uniqueFileName
            };
            _employeeRepository.Add(newEmployee);
            return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = newEmployee.Id });
        }

        return View();

    }
```

And this is my View

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="create" method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Surname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname..." />
            <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email..." />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Area" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="Area" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Area>()">
                <option value="">Please Select..</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Area" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input asp-for="Photo" name="Create" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File...</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
</form>
```

When i try To upload the img in the browser it doesnt Throw any exeption, it just doesnt Upload the image to the database and the column is NULL.

thank you in advance to everybody for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Create` view, you add extra `name="Create"` for `Photo` field which leads to the failure of model binding.You need to match the name to the model's field name.

Change below code from

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input asp-for="Photo" name="Create" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
            <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File...</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
            <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File...</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class EmployeeCreateViewModel
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Hamza El Aouane hello, have you resolved the problem?